# Know when a property has been set to an object using array notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, setter

I have an object that is used as a hash table to store key value pairs in javascript:

```
Storage["key"] = "value".
```

I've found we can use defineSetter to have setters for each key, however, we need to know all key names beforehand. Is there a way of doing something whenever a value is set this way?

So for example, when doing:

```
Storage["key"] = "value";
```

I want it to be handled by a custom method like:

```
customMethod : function(aKey, aValue) {
  //do something with these two params
  // inform somebody else about this.
}
```

Thoughts/Suggestions?

Comment: Uhm... yeah using such a `setValueForKey` method would be the only way. It is not a real setter though... what's your question now?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep using the array notation for this, to avoid having to refactor a lot of code. There's a bug in safari with HTML5 localStorage, and I wanted to workaround it with the less amounts of changes possible.

Comment: I think I understood.... unfortunately something like this is not possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't currently a way to catch all property assignments. Firefox 4 introduced an experimental [JavaScript Proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which would allow you to do this (have a proxy forward all calls to an inner object but also trigger some additional action when properties are set) but it would probably be an overkill here - even if this API were stable and implemented in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `__defineSetter__` of the object to gain finer control. Caveat: Won't work in all browsers!

See this post for more details: [John Resig: JavaScript Getters and Setters](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)